# Why is there a constant in the objective function of the *best subset selection problem*?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, quadratic-programming

This [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04527.pdf) presents the following formulation of the *best subset selection problem*

$$\min_{\|\beta\|_0\leq k}\frac{1}{2}\|y-X\beta\|^2_2$$

I wonder where the $1/2$ comes from. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is just for convenience, so that the Hessian of the objective does not have a factor of two.

The argmin (optimal value of $\beta$) is the same, whether or not the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ is included.

Note that rather than $\frac{1}{2}$, some "authors" use $\frac{1}{2n}$, This also does not affect the argmin.

Comment: Well, the square on the norm is also optional in same sense as the 0.5. Needed if you want a QP though.

Comment: @ ErlingMOSEK Yes that is true. And as a true conic man, I know you appreciate the potential advantages, including not squaring the condition number. Nevertheless, least squares, and to a large extent, nonlinear least squares, is the genesis for the 1/2.

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone, could you please clarify in more details *so that the Hessian of the objective does not have a factor of two* (the rest is rather clear)

Comment: @k88074 Without the factor of 1/2 the Hessian of the objective would be $2X^TX$. With the factor of 1/2, the Hessian is $X^TX$.

Comment: I the following reasoning correct? If want to minimize the objective (forget the constraint), I set the first derivative of the objective to zero, that is $-2Xy+2X^\top~X\beta=0$. Why does the $2X^\top~X$ bother us? We still get the same $\beta$

Comment: Yes, you get the same optimal $\beta$. So it really doesn't matter. Someone just liked having Hessian without the factor of 2. That's all. I think the origin for the people who do it this way is Quadratic Programming.